# Comment Page URL for entry

Tags: ee2

So. I have one channel
3 categories in this channel
and 5 entries

Every entry need comment form

How i can do that?
What i should put in Channel Preferences - Comment Page URL ?
And how to create template for comments?

Comment: ExpressionEngine has decent documentation, and your question is clear, but very poorly written. I understand if English isn't your first language, but if we can't understand you and your follow up comments, it hurts this site.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to read and understand the documentation for this : https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/comment/ You can go down to [here for the comment form](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/comment/#comment-submission-form) specifically.

The Comment Page URL is also explained throughout this page, the Channel Preferences form field is also explained [here](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/channel_edit_preferences.html)

Essentually the Comment Page URL is really for if you have all your comments on the one page...